# What do you call different runs of a simulation

Tags: word-choice

I have a basic scenario that is going to have a 'typical' set of settings (flow rate, temperature, etc).
Then there will also be a  Max flow rate. 
Then there will also be a Min flow rate.

For each of the three, I need to do a series of calculations.

I'm struggling to think of a good word to describe the three. There will be 3 "runs" (?) of the scenario? 
Configurations?

I've done a fair bit of googling around simulations, not finding anything that sounds right.

'Run' would be acceptable. Just seems like there might be a better word choice. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: "Run" is by far the most common term.

Comment: Are the settings the same across all scenarios or do they differ? If the settings are the same 'iteration' would work as in "There will be 3 iterations of the scenario". If the settings are different then 'test case' would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you intend by *scenario*. If you mean *settings*, then *configuration* is appropriate. If you mean *performance*, then use *run*.

Your sample sentence is

> There will be 3 ___ of the scenario.

The main issue with *run* is that it doesn't unambiguously indicate that each would have a different configuration. It simply says that "the" scenario would be exercised three times.

The subtler issue with *configuration* is that if the word is read as a verb, it means you're going to tinker with the scenario three times, which isn't what you intend. (The reading with *configuration* as a noun does come across strongly, though, so this is a minor objection.)

I suggest using the word *variant*:

> **Variant**
>   A form or version of something that differs in some respect from other forms of the same thing or from a standard.
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/variant)

That is, "There will be 3 variants of the scenario." This assumes the *settings* interpretation. For the *performance* interpretation, try:

> I will run three variants of the scenario.

Comment: Great answer. Variant is a nice word choice. I would love to hear more answers, but Variant is a good choice, better than my 'Run' so Im going to mark it as the answer.